# How to automatically scroll datagrid from view model with template datastudio for WinUI pattern

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3

Could you please help me to get an idea of how to autoscroll datagrid list while processing the list from the view model.

Here is an idea, I have a list of items loaded to datagrid, then I press the button and do some operations on each item from the view model, now I want that once item has been processed in view model, the DataGrid has scrolled the list to the processed item and so on until the last item is processed.

I'm using a template studio for WinUI with dependency injection, the problem is that I can;t get an idea of what would be the proper way to update view from view model....

Kind of lost in the MVVM pattern rules and practices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataGrid`'s `ScrollIntoView` method.

Now, since your view model knows when an item is "processed", you can create a `ItemProcessed` event in your view model and subscribe to this event.

For example,

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
...
    public event EventHandler<object>? ItemProcessed;

    private void OnItemProcessed(object item)
    {
        ItemProcessed?.Invoke(this, item);
    }
...
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        this.ViewModel.ItemProcessed += ViewModel_ItemProcessed;
    }

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; }

    private void ViewModel_ItemProcessed(object? sender, Item item)
    {
        // Don't forget to name your DataGrid.
        this.DataGridControl.ScrollIntoView(item, column: null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get to solve your problem?